# Why does calling mro() on a class return a list instead of a tuple?

Tags: python, method-resolution-order

You can obtain the MRO (Method Resolution Order) of a class `C` with either the `__mro__` attribute or the `mro()` method:

```
>>> C.__mro__
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> C.mro()
[<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>]
```

`__mro__` is a read-only attribute of an immutable tuple, but `mro()` returns a list.

I know that metaclasses can override `mro()` to customize the order, but that's not what's happening in this example class `C`. Even `object` returns a list:

```
>>> object.mro()
[<class 'object'>]
```

The fact that it's a mutable list would suggest modifying it serves some purpose, but changing the list has no effect on the actual MRO resolution process. In fact, a different list is returned every time `mro()` is called:

```
>>> x, y = object.mro(), object.mro()
>>> x is y, id(x), id(y)
(False, 123145300859648, 123145300859584)
```

Several sources describe `mro()` as returning a tuple. [The Python 2.3 Method Resolution Order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) still referenced by the current documentation shows `mro()` returning a tuple. In addition, a section of [PEP 447](https://peps.python.org/pep-0447/#aside-attribute-resolution-algorithm-in-python) shows the pseudo-code of the then-current implementation of `object.__getattribute__` where `mro()` is expected to return a tuple:

```
def _PyType_Lookup(tp, name):
    mro = tp.mro()
    assert isinstance(mro, tuple)
```

So why is `mro()` returning a list rather than a tuple? I can't find anything in the documentation that explains this.

Comment: Probably it's still a list due to retrompatibility